# How to combine sql select queries for this situation?

Tags: mysql, select

i'm writing a chat app with php/mysql

i have 3 tables: `user, room` and `room_participant` with these structures:

```
user: id, username
room: id, title
room_participant: room_id, user_id
```

Now i want to get list of all rooms along with list of all participants in each room.

Until now i just select all rooms from room table and iterate through all rooms and select users information out of each entry, which is very inefficient.

Is there any way to combine all these select into only 1 select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain about this without testing, but give it a try:

```
SELECT
   room.*, 
   user.* 
FROM room 
  JOIN room_participant ON room_id = room_participant.id
  JOIN user ON room_participant.user_id = user.id
ORDER BY room.id
```

To deduplicate rooms, use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

**UPDATE** `GROUP_CONCAT()` modified to return `id|username`

```
SELECT
   room.id, room.name
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user.id,'|',user.username)) AS userlist 
FROM room 
  JOIN room_participant ON room_id = room_participant.id
  JOIN user ON room_participant.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY room.id, room.name
ORDER BY room.id
```

With the `userlist` generated by `GROUP_CONCAT` as `id|name,id|name,id|name` you can use PHP `explode()` to separate them.

```
// Split the list on the commas
$users = explode(",", $userlist);


$final_users = array();
// Then split each on the `|`
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $split_user = explode("|", $user);

  // Append each as a new associative array to $final_users
  $final_users[] = array('id' => $split_user[0], 'username' => $split_user[1]);
}

// Now you have an array of users as id, username
var_dump($final_users);
```

Comment: your second join has a typo: `ON room_participant.user_id`

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, it works but the query return multiple records with same room_id when there are more than 2 participants in that room. Can i group the user entries inside a record (something like an array of users in a field of a room record)?

Comment: @Peacemoon Try addition above using `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  It will only return usernames though, not both usernames and user ids

Comment: @Michael: so is it possible to get both username and id for the user list?

Comment: @Michael: i ended up with the solution of using GROUP_CONCAT for both usernames and ids. I can then manipulate the list later with php code. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Peacemoon Not sure how I would do it straight in SQL, but see above.  The `GROUP_CONCAT` now returns both id and username, then PHP splits them apart with two `explode()` calls

Comment: @Peacemoon Ah -  your comment came in as I was typing up the PHP to manipulate the group_concat list...

Comment: @Michael let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1786/discussion-between-peacemoon-and-michael)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to do two queries, and then match things up in whatever is using MySQL, e.g. PHP.

These two:

```
SELECT id, title
  FROM room;

SELECT rp.room_id, rp.user_id, u.username
  FROM room_participant AS rp
       INNER JOIN user as u ON rp.user_id = u.id;
```

Or these two:

```
SELECT id, username
  FROM user;

SELECT rp.room_id, rp.user_id, r.title
  FROM room_participant AS rp
       INNER JOIN room as r ON rp.user_id = r.id;
```

Which two queries make sense depends on what you're doing with the info really.

You could go a step further and select all three separately:

```
SELECT *
  FROM room;

SELECT *
  FROM user;

SELECT *
  FROM room_participant;
```

Note: It's probably better to state the columns, rather than using '*', just in case in the future new columns are added to the table that you're not really interested in for these queries.

Obviously, you'd then have to match everything up in whatever is using MySQL, e.g. PHP.  You could create a list of rooms and users from the selected info, and then match them up with something like:

```
// Use MySQL to populate $roomList from database, then do...
foreach ($roomList as $room)
{
    $id    = $room['id'];
    $title = $room['title'];

    $this->roomList[$id] = new Room($id, $title);
}

// Use MySQL to populate $userList from database, then do...
foreach ($userList as $user)
{
    $id       = $user['id'];
    $username = $user['username'];

    $this->userList[$id] = new User($id, $username);
}

// Use MySQL to populate $roomParticipantList from database, then do...
foreach ($roomParticipantList as $roomParticipant)
{
    $room = $this->roomList[$roomParticipant['room_id']];
    $user = $this->userList[$roomParticipant['user_id']];

    // You could do one/both of these, depending on requirements.
    $room->enterUser($user);
    $user->joinRoom($room);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think it's really difficult to do everything with only 1 query.